# how to insert query result to a temp data in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want to know how to store my query below into a temp data from SQL,

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 
    Xdate, Xhostname, COUNT(Xhostname) AS total 
FROM
    weblogs 
WHERE
    Xdate  
    AND xhostname IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    Xhostname, Xdate 
ORDER BY 
    total DESC

SELECT distinct top 10 Xdate, Xuser, count (Xuser) as total 
FROM weblogs 
WHERE Xdate and Xuser is not null 
GROUP BY Xuser, Xdate 
ORDER BY total DESC

SELECT distinct top 10 Xdate, Xsrcip, count (Xsrcip) as total 
FROM weblogs 
WHERE Xdate and Xuser is not null 
GROUP BY Xsrcip, Xdate 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you this in 3 different temp tables use something like **SELECT distinct top 10 Xdate, Xhostname, count(Xhostname) as total INTO #tempweblogs from weblogs where Xdate and xhostname is not null group by Xhostname, Xdate** per each select statement

Comment: Hi Sam, this will be stored on a single temp table so that i could pull its result and put it on my crystal report, let me know if this syntax is still possible
Thanks

Comment: If it's a single temp table first do a CREATE TABLE #tempTab (Xdate as datetime, Srcip VARCHAR(10), Total INT) and then insert the data to this. However if you're retrieving data from the same session only will this work. If you store this data in one session and try to retrieve in another session use ##tempTab. Note the double #.

Comment: Hi Sam,
I get this error when running the query the first line is a success but the second one i get this error There is already an object named '##Temp' in the database.

Comment: posted the whole code as the answer. Check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE ##tempTab (Xdate datetime, XUser VARCHAR(100), Total INT)

INSERT INTO ##tempTab
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 
    Xdate, Xhostname AS , COUNT(Xhostname) AS total 
FROM
    weblogs 
WHERE
    Xdate  
    AND xhostname IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    Xhostname, Xdate 

UNION
SELECT distinct top 10 Xdate, Xuser, count (Xuser) as total 
FROM weblogs 
WHERE Xdate and Xuser is not null 
GROUP BY Xuser, Xdate 

UNION

SELECT distinct top 10 Xdate, Xsrcip AS XUser, count (Xsrcip) as total 
FROM weblogs 
WHERE Xdate and Xuser is not null 
GROUP BY Xsrcip, Xdate
```